# Docker Running running within container but not reachable through browser

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Being new to Docker, I am following a tutorial but using my own personal MERN-stack project. My personal project folder structure consists of a frontend folder and a backend folder and my Dockerfile placed in the root directory. My frontend is uses localhost:3000 and my backend at localhost:5000. I am trying to view my application in the browser; however, it takes me to a page that states `this site can't be reached` for `http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost:5000` and for `http://172.17.0.3:3000` its just a blank forever loading page.
If it helps, i'm using a macOS.

steps i've taken:

`docker build -t foodcore:1.0 .`

`docker run -p 3001:3000 -p 5001:5000 foodcore:1.0`

outcome in my terminal:

```
> server@1.0.0 dev
> concurrently "nodemon server.js" "npm run client"

[0] [nodemon] 2.0.6
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[1] 
[1] > server@1.0.0 client
[1] > cd .. && cd client && npm start
[1] 
[1] 
[1] > client@0.1.0 start
[1] > react-scripts start
[1] 
[0] Thu, 07 Jan 2021 01:15:15 GMT body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares at server.js:12:9
[0] Thu, 07 Jan 2021 01:15:15 GMT body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option at node_modules/body-parser/index.js:105:29
[0] Listening at: http://localhost:5000
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.3/
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /FoodCore/client/public
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
[1] Starting the development server...
[1] 
[1] Compiled successfully!
[1] 
[1] You can now view client in the browser.
[1] 
[1]   Local:            http://localhost:3000
[1]   On Your Network:  http://172.17.0.3:3000
[1] 
[1] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[1] To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

docker container

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                              NAMES
6c5abad55b1b   foodcore:1.0          "npm run dev"            32 minutes ago   Up 32 minutes   0.0.0.0:3001->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp     optimistic_chandrasekhar
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /FoodCore

COPY . /FoodCore

WORKDIR /FoodCore/client

RUN npm install

WORKDIR /FoodCore/server

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Thank you very much for taking your time reading this.

**UPDATE**

Turns out i was trying to access http://localhost:3000 but i set my application to run at 3001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Turns out by through this outline

`docker run -p <host_port>:<container_port>`

i was initially setting my host port to 3001 instead of 3000. Thus, accessing the wrong port